# Error installing dependencies of openmediavault

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, web-server, media-server

I am trying to install openmediavault on my raspbian jessie, but I keep getting the below error , even though I have tried with --fix-missing.

```
$ sudo apt-get install openmediavault -y --force-yes
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openmediavault : Depends: php5-pam but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: proftpd-mod-vroot but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: php5-proctitle but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a answer from [here](http://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/6332-openmediavault-transmissionbt-fails-to-install-on-Raspberry-Pi-due-to-dependenci/).

> I made armhf transmission packages on the RPi and they are in the testing repo. Enable the testing repo on the Primary tab of omv-extras and it should find the packages.

Hope this can help.

Comment: how exactly do you 'enable the testing repo on the primary tab of omv-extras'?